# <video onclick> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-video

Javascript onclick on a HTML video element is not working.

EDIT: In Firefox (66.0.5 (64-Bit)) dont work. In Chrome (74.0.3729.131) works.
No errors in the console.

I will put a text in a div box when the video is clicking/started (with video lenght to wait).

```js
function myfunction () {
  console.log("onclick");
  document.getElementById("videotextbox").innerHTML = "VIDEO-INFO";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video onclick="myfunction()" id="videoid" width="600" controls>
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>

<div id="videotextbox"></div>
```

w3schools write:

> Supported HTML tags: All HTML elements, EXCEPT: <base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>

Please a solution without jquery or ajax.

Comment: what error do you get? Did you check your console log?

Comment: Your code works fine. You must have another issue. See https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/bwd98xtn/

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Yes. i have checked your code work perfectly. i think there are another issues. please check console and find out the issue

Comment: the code given works fine. but due to browser issue it may not work check for latest version.

Comment: in mozilla its not working but in chrome the code works fine.

Comment: Do you get the message "No video with supported format and MIME type found"?

Comment: @RezaSaadati no. You must use a own video in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the `controls`. No browser does expose when users click on the controls of MediaElements.

You can try to click on the play button or the timeline from Chrome and you'll see that the click events are actually stopped.

In Firefox, these controls are covering the whole video element, and thus, you don't have any click event getting out on your element.
<sub>(Technically, Chrome's too, and I suspect this is [a bug they left](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884108#c_ts1537256270) when they made their updated player).</sub>

So if you really need the click events, then don't set the `controls` attribute:

```js
document.querySelector('video').onclick = e => 
  console.log('clicked');
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm" autoplay></video>
```

But generally, you don't need to listen for click events, but rather for [Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) such as `playing`, `pause`, `seek` etc.

```js
const vid = document.querySelector('video');

['playing', 'pause', 'seeked', 'ended'].forEach(t => 
   vid.addEventListener(t, e => console.log(t))
);
```

```css
video{
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm" controls></video>
```

Comment: The "MediaEvents" is the solution. But, why is on the end a "pause" and not a "end"?

Comment: @suka because I didn't include a listener for the ended event.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

use HTML Audio/Video DOM ended Event.

```
var myvideo = document.getElementById("videoid");
myvideo.onended = function() {
  document.getElementById("videotextbox").innerHTML = "VIDEO-INFO";
};
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp